# preview uploaded images inside draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui

I would like to know how I can preview images inside draggable before I upload them. I have some code that I want to intergrade with previewing images iside draggable

This is my code for preview image inside draggable I want to be able to separate them and drag each image individually.

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {
  var fileList = this.files;

  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    $('.preview-area').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }


}
$('#draggableHelper').draggable();
$('#image').resizable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
  <div id="image" class="preview-area"></div>

</div>
```

This is my code that I have already for inserting text in a container I would like to combine this and the image preview. the script below works great I can preview unlimited text and drag them individually Please help me thank you

```
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
/** Make div draggable **/
$('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
        }
    }
});
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
$(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
return false;
});


 $(document).on("click", function()
 {
var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
if (editingText.length)
{
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
}
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function () {
        selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
}
};


var vm=function(){
var self=this;
self.items=ko.observableArray();
self.textContent = ko.observable('');
self.init=function(){
    self.items([]);
}
self.remove=function(item){
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
}
 self.addNew = function() {
  self.items.push( self.textContent() );
  self.textContent('');
}
self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out the snippet:

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {
  var fileList = this.files;

  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    var imgEl =  $('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
    $('<div class="preview-area"/>').append(imgEl).appendTo('body').draggable();
    imgEl.load(function() {
      $(this).resizable();
    });
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
  <div id="image" class="preview-area"></div>

</div>
```